# Why does pyspark give "we couldn't find any external IP address" on macOS?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I use `pyspark` and got a warning below. Could someone tell me how to fix it? Is this something I should be worried about?

Code:

```
lines = sc.textFile("README.md") #worked
lines.count() #error
```

Warning:

> 16/02/24 08:20:39 WARN : Your hostname, a.local resolves to a loopback/non-reachable address: fe80:0:0:0:f09c:b1ff:fef2:170c%awdl0, but we couldn't find any external IP address!

Answer (score 4):

Spark resolves your hostname to an address to establish communication channels between nodes (the driver and executors) for a Spark application.

It looks like your machine has various names (possibly in `/etc/hosts`) and some of them are not resolved which Spark can use.

You can explicitly set the local hostname to `localhost` (which is probably resolvable) for `spark-shell` using `SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME` environment variable as follows:

```
SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=localhost ./bin/spark-shell
```

Or:

```
./bin/spark-shell -c spark.driver.host=localhost
```

Refer to [Environment Variables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables) in the documentation for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Add local path in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`:

```
SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1
```